# Set carat/cursor from edittext1 to edittext2

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've already searched how to do this but couldn't find any solution. Here it goes, I have edittext1 and edittext2, while the carat/cursor is positioned in edittext1 then I pressed "Next/Enter" key in soft keyboard, the carat/cursor must be positioned in edittext2. The snippet below received the event when I pressed the "Next/Enter" key but didn't move the carat/cursor in edittext2.

```
    edittext1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() 
    {       
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        {
            if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
            {
                Editable e = edittext2.getText();
                Selection.setSelection(e,e.length());
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Any inputs will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:
if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
{
  edittext2.requestFocus();
}

The cursor moves to edittext2.

Comment: Glad to know. A "vote up" to my post will be gracefully accepted ;)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than doing it in code, can't you use the [`android:nextFocusDown`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3anextFocusDown) and [`android:nextFocusUp`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3anextFocusUp) in your XML?  Here are some references:

- [Handling UI Events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#HandlingFocus)
- [View documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#FocusHandling)

**EDIT**
With your accepted answer it looks like you have a solution that works, however I thought I'd get the XML route to work too.  So here is a working version of your layout elements:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView 
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextViewRecipient"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:hint="To"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editTextComposeMessage"
    android:nextFocusUp="@+id/editTextComposeMessage"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextComposeMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/autoCompleteTextViewRecipient"
    android:nextFocusUp="@+id/autoCompleteTextViewRecipient"/>
```

Differences are that the `AutoCompleteTextView` now has a `nextFocusDown`, the `EditText` has a `nextFocusUp`, and both have `imeOptions` set to `actionNext`

Comment: Still it didn't work...  <AutoCompleteTextView
   android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextViewRecipient"  
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:completionThreshold="1"
   android:inputType="text"
   android:maxLines="1"
   android:hint="To"
   android:nextFocusUp="@+id/editTextComposeMessage"/>  <EditText android:id="@+id/editTextComposeMessage"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:nextFocusDown="@+id/autoCompleteTextViewRecipient"/>

Comment: @exception updated my answer with a working version of your XML